# How do I reference a field in LINQ that is named using a reserved word?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

table:`UserTypes`

Fields:`row,name,Type`

This code is not working:

```
 Int64 row = 1;
var myType = (from b in dc.UserTypes where b.Row == user.Row  select b).Single();
myType.Type = "personalPage";
dc.SubmitChanges();
```

But, this code does...
     `dc.ExecuteQuery<UserType >("update dbo.UserType set Type='personalPage' where row={0}",user.Row` );

I get this error:

> Type the word is a word reserved.i can not user word`Type`

**EDIT**

dbml

```
  [Table(Name="dbo.UserType")]
  public partial class UserType
 {

     private long _Row;

     private string _Type;

     public UserType()
     {
     }

     [Column(Storage="_Row", DbType="BigInt NOT NULL")]
     public long Row
     {
     get
      {
        return this._Row;
       }
     set
       {
        if ((this._Row != value))
        {
            this._Row = value;
        }
        }
    }

    [Column(Storage="_Type", DbType="NVarChar(500) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false)]
    public string Type
     {
    get
    {
        return this._Type;
    }
    set
    {
        if ((this._Type != value))
        {
            this._Type = value;
        }
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: Yup. That's why it is a bad idea to use reserved words like type as field names.

Comment: If you use the IDE to set up the mapping (DBML), it usually gets this right automatically...

Comment: @JohnFx - in his defense, it's a C# reserved word not a `SQL` one - maybe he's a DB person but not a OO programmer.

Comment: I doubt that you get "Type the word is a word reserved.i can not user word Type" as the error. Please post the exact error message. Please be very specific about where you are getting this message. Is it at runtime, or at compile time. Since "Type" is not a reserved word on SQL Server, something is not adding up here.

Comment: @JNK If they are not an OO programmer, then why are they writing code?

Comment: @JohnFx not all programmers are OO programmers. I write plenty of code but would never call myself an OO programmer. Should I trade in my computer for an easy-bake oven?

Comment: @JohnFx - because he has to do it for his job.  I'm saying, maybe the DB was developed without Linq in mind, when `TYPE` would be perfectly valid from a DB-only perspective.

Comment: @JohnFx even without linq or OO  "Type"  is a horrible field name. Common sense says that is going to be a reserved word somewhere down the line. I'm not big on the idea of a DB guy not having knowledge of issues that their naming conventions might cause downstream.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go into your LINQ to SQL DBML mapping and change the mapping for `UserType.Type` from being to a column named "Type" to a column named "[Type]". You can do this in the designer, or manually.

Answer (score 4):

You can reference it as `UserType.@Type` in your code.

Comment: Thanks! I had a similar situation where I was working with a legacy DB with a table named "event". This was a lifesaver. We were considering using a table alias, a special View, etc. Using `@event.Where(...)` did the trick.